# Regex for extracting links with specified attributes

Tags: regex, hyperlink, extract, nofollow

I'm trying to build regex to extract links from text which have not **rel="nofollow"**.

Example:

`aiusdiua asudauih <a rel="nofollow" hre="http://uashiuadha.asudh/adas>adsaag</a> uhwaida <br> asdgydug <a href="http://asdha.sda/uduih/dufhuis>aguuia</a>`

Thanks!

Comment: ... And is there any possibility that you can use a parser instead of regex?

Comment: no i want to make it with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will do the job:

```
<a (?![^>]*?rel="nofollow")[^>]*?href="(.*?)"
```

The wanted urls will be in the capture group #1. E.g. in Ruby it would be:

```
if input =~ /<a (?![^>]*?rel="nofollow")[^>]*?href="(.*?)"/
    match = $~[1]
end
```

Since it accepts `[^>]*?` before `rel` in the *negative lookahead*, `href` or anything else can come before `rel`. If `href` comes after `rel`, it'll of course also be ok.

Comment: My experience with regex Always take care while using .*?

Comment: @regexhacks: why should one take care when using `.*?`

Comment: @regexhacks I agree. One must be careful with all quantifiers that accepts nothing or unlimited.

Comment: @regexhacks Since it accepts `[^>]*?`before `rel` in the *negative lookahead*, `href` or anything else can come before `rel`. If href comes after rel, it'll of course also be ok.

Comment: @regexhacks Thanks for asking for details, it was probably needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`<(?:A|AREA)\b[^<>]*?(?!rel="nofollow")[^<>]*?href=['"]([^>"]*)[^>]*?>`

if you are using .net regex then

```
<(?:A|AREA)\b[^<>]*?(?!rel="nofollow")[^<>]*?href=['"](?<URL>[^>"]*)[^>]*?>
```

data lies in group named **URL** or group 1

Comment: I think you will have to fix two issues on this answer:
1) Right now it will find strings that actually have `rel="nofollow"`, but the question asked for the opposite.
2) It won't match if `href` comes before `rel` in a `a` tag.

Comment: It will still match `<a href="http://uashiuadha.asudh/adas" rel="nofollow">`, won't it? I think you need one more edit session for that regex :-)

Comment: Yep! It should. Yours one in better than mine! :-) I won't edit. supporting answer.